# jquery post code based on scroll position fires twice

Tags: jquery, post

I have a piece of jquery to load new posts on my blog, the issue is that it runs twice meaning the posts are duplicated. I would also like to work out a way to make it run when the user is still a few pixels say 50 from the bottom of the document. (figure that is straightforward).

The bug is reported on the site where I got the code before tweaking it:
http://blog.hycus.com/2011/03/15/infinite-scrolling-like-new-twitter-with-php-mysql-jquery

One comment suggests using .data() but I'm not really sure how that would work. This code is being run from a separate js file with the link to it in the body text. Firebug reports two post requests and I end up with the blog posts displayed twice.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() === $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
            $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
            $.post("blog/loadmore", {pid: $(".blogpost:last").attr("id")}, function(html){
                if(html){
                    $("#bloglist").append(html);
                    $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
                }else{
                    $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');
                }
            });
        };
    });
});
```

I can't post an answer to my own question... I solved it:

This seems to solve my problem, if anyone has a better fix then let me know.

Also have tried a couple of things to make the page load happen before reaching the end of the page (I thought if ($(window).scrollTop()+50 === $(document).height() - $(window).height()) might do the trick) but they didn't work.

```
var lid = $(".blogpost:last").attr("id");
$(document).ready(function() {
$(this).scrollTop(0);

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() === $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        if(lid !== $(".blogpost:last").attr("id")){
            $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
            $.post("blog/loadmore", {
                pid: $(".blogpost:last").attr("id")
            }, function(html) {
                if (html) {
                    $("#bloglist").append(html);
                    $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
                } else {
                    $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');
                }
            });
            lid = $(".blogpost:last").attr("id");
        }
    };
});
```

});

Comment: When I [made a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xUsEA/), with some tweaks to make it work on JSFiddle, I don't see duplicated rows. Are you sure your server script isn't outputting more than one blog post, but it looks like jQuery is firing twice?

Comment: Hi Jared, Firebug is showing two posts and they receive the same data. I can't see any reason why the server script would duplicate. The idea is it pulls the next ten posts when it hits the base of the page.

Comment: This might be caused by the first iteration not moving the page fast enough so if I keep scrolling it runs using the same last id because the new id has yet to load. Is there a way I can record the last id between runnings and then if it is the same not run the post?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at that code, i didn't particularly like the way it was setup. The script needs some caching of the elements so you're not constantly calling on the same selector, over and over again, for instance.

I used an `inproc` (in process) variable within the `onDOMReady` anonymous function callback. This is set at the top-level, but due to the closure that the anonymous function provides, that variable will stay available to the containing functions. Here, I test to see if it's `true` or not.

You'll see I move all of your jQuery calls to the beginning and added them as variables. This is called caching, and helps prevent making the same requests over and over again in the same script. It's much more efficient. Note, having `$('div#id')` will work, but it's unnecessary to prefix an `id`; just start with the `id`, such as `$('#id')`. Anything before it is really unnecessary, IMO.

I also set a `200px` preload distance. `50px` is not as high as you probably think; it's barely noticeable what the different is.

The timeout is entirely meant to delay the loading of the content so you can test the scroll. Have Firebug open to see the `console.log()` message.

This script is heavy on test-related variables and functions, but you should be able to remove anything that says "For test purposes" or some variation of that, and have it work fine.

```
// For test purposes.
var i = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){
    var inproc = false,
        id,
        $win = $(window),
        $doc = $(document),
        $bloglist = $("#bloglist"),
        $loadmore = $('#loadmoreajaxloader'),
        // For test purposes.
        dummycontent = $('.dummycontent').html(),
        loadtimeout = false;

    // Note, load is for testing; it goes with the setTimeout().
    var callbackBlogLoaded = function(html){
        var self = this;

        // For testing purposes.
        if (loadtimeout !== false) {
            loadtimeout = false;

            setTimeout(function(html){
                callbackBlogLoaded.call(self, html);
            }, 3000);

            return false;
        }

        inproc = false;

        // For test purposes.
        i++;
        html = dummycontent;
        if (i > 5) html = '';

        if (html) {
            // For test purposes.
            $bloglist.append('<p style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">i is ' + i + ' of 5 total</p>' + html);
            $loadmore.hide();
        } else {
            // <center> is deprecated; use a class on a P or DIV instead.
            $loadmore.html('<p class="center">No more posts to show.</p>');
        }
    };

    // For test purposes.
    $bloglist.append($('.dummycontent').html());

    $win.scroll(function(){
        // You need to subtract the scroll-load pad distance from the
        // right-side height calculation, not .scrollTop().
        if ($win.scrollTop() > ($doc.height() - $win.height() - 200)){
            if (inproc == true) {
                // For testing purposes.
                console.log('Content load blocked: In process with another request.');

                return false;
            }

            inproc = true;
            id = $bloglist.has(':last').attr('id');

            // For test purposes
            id = 10;
            loadtimeout = true;

            $loadmore.show();

            // The /echo/html/ is for testing purposes.
            $.post("/echo/html/", { pid: id }, callbackBlogLoaded);
        };
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xUsEA/2/